# Is the sequence $x$ statistically convergent to $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, intuition, density-function

A sequence $y=(y_n)_n$ is said to be a statistically convergent to $\lambda$ if for any $\epsilon>0$ the set $\{n\in\mathbb N: |y_n-\lambda|\geq\epsilon\}$ has [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) $0$.

Consider the following sequence :

$$x=(~\underbrace{0,0,\dots,0}_{100\text{ copies}}~,~   \overbrace{1,1,\dots,1}^{10\text{ copies}}~,~ \underbrace{0,0,\dots,0}_{100^2\text{ copies}}~,~ \overbrace{1,1,\dots,1}^{10^2\text{ copies}}~,~ \underbrace{0,0,\dots,0}_{100^3\text{ copies}}~,~   \overbrace{1,1,\dots,1}^{10^3\text{ copies}}~,~ \dots)$$

This sequence is not [almost convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_convergent_sequence) because there exists no $\Omega\in \mathbb R$ such that $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\frac{x_{n+1}+x_{n+2}+\dots+x_{n+k}}{k}=\Omega$, for each $n\in \mathbb N$.

**My Question :** Is the sequence $x$ statistically convergent to $0$?

How can I prove or disprove that? How we deal here with natural density?

This sequence is from Proposition 1.1 in  *Miller, H. I.; Orhan, C.*, [**On almost convergent and statistically convergent subsequences**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1013877718406), Acta Math. Hung. 93, No. 1-2, 135-151 (2001). [ZBL0989.40002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0989.40002), [MR1924673](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1924673).

Comment: Can you define "statistically convergent to $0$" ?

Comment: Also are you sure that the sequence is not almost convergent? It looks to me that for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$ we have that the limit equals $0$. We have that sum $\sum_{i=1}^{100^n}x_{i}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n 10^i\leq 10^{n+1}$ so we have that $\sum_{i=1}^{100^n}x_{i}/100^n\leq 10^{n+1}/100^n=10^{1-n}$

Comment: @GabrielRomon I've edited my question by including the definition of statistical convergence.

Comment: @kingW3 In the following paper (see Proposition 1.1), I've seen this result. But I cannot understand the part of statistical convergence.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1013877718406

Comment: @BijanDatta I have included the reference mentioned in your comment into the question, since it is a reasonable way to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). I will also mention that [using citation helper](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22008/lets-get-mathoverflows-citation-helper-here-too) (which is available when editing any post) you can get nicely formatted references relatively easily.

Comment: @kingW3 I have tried to offer an argument why sequences of this form are not almost convergent [in an answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279604/is-there-any-statistically-convergent-real-sequence-which-is-not-almost-converg/3280571#3280571). The main thing here is that we have arbitrarily long segments consisting of zeroes and arbitrarily long segments consisting of ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a sequence consisting of zeroes and ones. So it is statistically convergent to zero, if and only if the set
$$A=\{n\in\mathbb N; x_n=1\}$$
has density zero, i.e., that $d(A)=0$.

Let $A(n)=|A\cap\{1,2,\dots,n\}$| denote the number of elements in $A$ which are less than or equal to $n$. Recall that the asymptotic density is defined as the limit of the fraction $A(n)/n$, taking limes superior/inferior we get the upper/lower asymptotic density.

I will also remind that in general when we have a set which has this type of "block structure", it suffices to check the value of $A(n)/n$ at the beginning end ends of the blocks to get the asymptotic density. See, for example, Proposition 2 in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126745/references-on-density-of-subsets-of-mathbbn/126795#126795).

In our case, the values of $A(n)/n$ at the ends of the blocks are
$$\frac{10}{10+100},\frac{10+10^2}{10+100+10^2+100^2}, \frac{10+10^2+10^3}{10+100+10^2+100^2+10^3+100^3}.$$
Using Stolz-Cesaro theorem we can see that limit of the above sequence is equal to
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{10^n}{10^n+100^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+10^n}=0.$$
This show that $\overline d(A)=0$ and, consequently, $d(A)=0$.

---

<sup>1</sup>I am using Stolz-Cesaro theorem in the "sum version", for comparing the two versions of this result see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100338/limit-of-quotient-of-two-series/100542#100542). Of course, it would be easy to calculate the limit even without this theorem - we basically just need to compute the sums of two geometric series.